# Why would we useCallback in useIsMounted hook to return the ref from the hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref, react-usecallback

In the following example taken from [usehooks-ts](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-is-mounted) website

```js
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

function useIsMounted() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true

    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }
  }, [])

  return useCallback(() => isMounted.current, [])
}

export default useIsMounted
```

Why do we return the `isMounted.current` as a callback and don't return just the value `isMounted.current`?

What would be an example where returning just `isMounted.current` as a value will be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the different implementation yourself to see what happens:

```
const UnmountingChild = ({ unmount }) => {
  const { isMounted, isMountedNC } = useIsMounted();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('IS MOUNTED BEFORE FETCH', isMounted()); // true
    console.log('IS MOUNTED NO CALLBACK BEFORE FETCH', isMountedNC.current); //true
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then((d) => {
      console.log('IS MOUNTED', isMounted()); //false
      console.log('IS MOUNTED NO CALLBACK', isMountedNC.current); //false
    });
    unmount(); // <-- This triggers the unmount of the component
  }, []);

  return <>Child</>;
};

function useIsMounted() {
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);

  return {
    isMounted: useCallback(() => isMounted.current, []),
    isMountedNC: isMounted,
  };
}
```

Check the demo [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k16l6q)

The usage of a callback is useful because it lets you to read directly the value of the `ref` with `ref.current` when needed , simply by calling `isMounted()`, if you want to directly return the `ref` you just have to make sure to return all the `ref` and not just `ref.current` because if you pass `ref.current` you will pass just the actual value and not the `mutable ref object` hence its value will always be stuck to `false`.
Returning the `ref` forces you to then read every time the `.current` property, and that's not very nice, and it could mislead people using the hook without knowing the internal implementation, while calling `isMounted()` is nicer to read, and to use and avoids usage troubles.

Comment: But I also wonder why would we use `useCallback` and not just wrap it in a simple callback? I mean I know that with `useCallback` we'll have the same reference to the function and without it we'll create new function every time, but what are the gains here and why would we bother using `useCallback` when it's not supposed to be overused?

Comment: That's up to you, usually in Custom hooks it is a good practice to use the React hooks when possible. There are people that wrap every function into `useCallback`, other people wrap every component in `React.memo`, in this case it's a good practice to memoize that function, since functions with no deps are worth to be memoized, I don't think it's an "overuse" case!